# Perception of time: 1 day to John is X days to Sally

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I'm a ruby programmer writing a calculator for a fun blog post.

I want to quantify the perception of time between two individuals.

John has lived 236676.87 hours

Sally has lived 438290.5 hours

1 day to John is 0.010140407890302081% of his life

1 day to Sally is 0.005475820260763124% of her life

How can I go about making a statement such as:

**"1 day to John is X days to Sally"**

Thank you for your help in advance. ~Joel

Comment: Well, you can just make the statement. What is your question? Are you asking what $X$ is?

Comment: Yes, I need to know the math to figure out X.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with actual "perception of time," which I'm sure is quite an interesting subject, but is off-topic here. It's more akin to defining a foot as the length of my foot, so that you and I have different ideas of feet we'd have different units of measure.

Comment: Right, just made for a fun blog post. Obviously many factors go into time perception, but time lived in relation to another is a way to make a perception of time calculator in an afternoon. :) The other guy talked with me in chat for a while and helped me through it so I gave him the points but thank you for your help and correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \mbox{let}\ j=\mbox{the number of hours that John has lived.} $$
$$ \mbox{let}\ s=\mbox{the number of hours that Sally has lived.} $$
So now we have
$$ \frac{1}{j} = \frac{x}{s} $$
$$ x= \frac{s}{j} = \mbox{the number of days that Sally lived in relation to John.}$$

Comment: what does the 1 represent (top left)? Is it 1 day? So since i'm doing everything in hours should it be 24? Can someone please show the work so I can turn it into a program? It's hard when I don't know how to do math like this.

Comment: @jBeas, it represents 1 day, which allows x to be in units of days.

Comment: You are being very kind. Thank you. I just don't understand. Until I can see it line for line in a real example I won't get how it works. I am going to just wait and offer a bounty for someone to show their work. Thank you for your help, I just know too little about this.

Comment: @jBeas, grab a calculator and input the hours for Sally divided by the hours for John. The answer is x.

Comment: 438290.5 / 236676.87 = 1.85185185185185

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21479/discussion-between-jbeas-and-k170).

Comment: @jBeas, perfect. That's exactly how many days Sally experiences, every time John experiences one day.

Comment: This is where I am at so far, still have to design a graphic for the article, put a shout out for you in there then I'll publish it. http://www.abetterdeveloper.com/perception_calculator

Comment: @jBeas, good job and thanks for the shout out! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$$1\text{ day}/J=X/S$$ where $J$ is the length of life of John and $S$ is the length of live of Sally. Solve for $X$. Be careful about units.

Comment: Not too worried about units because I don't know what they are :P

Comment: I'm still lost Thomas. Can you show me a written out example? I want to get this right.